# Referencing the Activity in a ViewHolder

Tags: android, performance, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, android-viewholder

Is it safe to keep a handle to the Activity in a ViewHolder that is stored with the `setTag` method?

I found this issue that claims that storing a reference to the Activity could result in memory leaks, but it has been fixed in Android 4.0: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18273

Concretely, I'm wondering if it's safe to have a ViewHolder that looks something like this:

```
class MyHolder {
  private Context context; // <<-- is this safe to keep here??
  private TextView textView;

  public MyHolder(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public void populate(Doc doc) {
    textView.setText(context.getString(doc.getTextId()));
  }

  public View inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
        R.layout.doc_item, parent, false);

    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.doc_item_text);

    return view;
  }
}
```

with a getView method in my ArrayAdapter like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {

    Doc doc = getItem(position);

    MyHolder holder;
    if (row != null) {
        holder = (MyHolder) row.getTag();
    } else {
        holder = new MyHolder(getContext());
        row = holder.inflate(parent);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder.populate(doc);

    return row;
}
```

(The code is a simplified version of the actual codebase just to get the point across.)

None of the example code I've seen stores references to anything but views in the holder. I'm wondering if that's by coincidence or by design.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of whether it would be safe in this instance, it's always best to keep Context references to a minimum. Everything you're doing with `context` in `MyHolder` can be translated to operations performed in `getView()` with the Context reference held in the Adapter. This would be by design, since there's certainly no need to have the multiple Context references that your design would require.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the somewhat contrived example. Sometimes when populating the holder, I want to reference some broader context (e.g. an instance of Picasso for loading a picture, or some in-memory datastore to decide how exactly to populate the view). It's nice having the populate method on the Holder itself, but it only works cleanest when you can pass in references to other parts of the app.

Comment: Assuming by cleanest, you mean from a code perspective, then it's just a matter of having a certain code block in one place and not the other, in which case, keeping in mind our goal of minimal Context references, it's preferable to have it in the Adapter. Basically, if it needs a Context, and it can be done in `getView()`, do it in `getView()`.